# Flexslider 2 slideshow horizontal & vertical viewport/browser scaling

Tags: css, slideshow, scale, viewport, flexslider

I've just integrated Flexslider 2 into an extremely simple portfolio webpage.

This is the first time I've used Flexslider, so far it's great but I'm having a little
trouble getting the slideshow to scale as I'd like when re-sizing the browser.

Here's an example of the page I've posted online:

http://www.thisisneil.com/rg-e/index.html

Currently the slideshow scales with the browser perfectly horizontally, but
due to the page size and slideshow positioning the bottom of the image
tends to get cropped. To resolve this I'd like the slideshow to also scale
vertically with the window, I just can't seem to get it to do so!

here's an example of how I'd ultimately like my Flexslider to behave:
(no matter the window size the slideshow will always re-format to
display the full image).

http://eastphotographic.com/artist.php?region=uk&div=Photography&artist=Linda%20Brownlee

So far I've tried adjusting the Flexslider CSS values and also containing
the whole slider within a separate div set to re-size with the window. I'm
clearly not doing anything correctly!

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add smoothHeight: true when calling flexslider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide", // set animation to slide
        smoothHeight: true // auto-adjust to fit the height of images
    });
});
```

Comment: Mihai, thanks for the response. smoothHeight should already be being called, both in the head
(as below) and enabled in the Flexslider source script… Still no joy - I'm not sure that smoothHeight actually has anything to do with the viewport scaling? Thanks again.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
 
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
 smoothHeight: true,
         controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
         start: function(slider) {
           $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
         },
         after: function(slider) {
           $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);

         }
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: Neil your slider is not loading correctly. I just found an error in your call: TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function - after: function(slider). I will look for a fix.

Comment: Neil I copied/pasted your code/resources in a fiddle (except jquery.js) http://jsfiddle.net/VKG4y/ and it works! So I think the problem is loading the jquery. At a first look I noticed you're loading jquery twice (from your server and from googleapis). Other than that your targeting controlsContainer: ".flex-container", but in your html the class is "flexcontainer".

Comment: Hi Mihali, thanks for your help today, I've just checked the fiddle link, the image still doesn't scale (to fit within the window without cropping) as I'm trying to get it to. I'll see if I can work this out tonight... you may have to bear with me, as you may have guessed im new to javascript! thanks again.  neil.

Comment: Just checked the fiddle again using Firefox responsive design view. The results are here http://htmldoc.net/examples/pics/fiddle.jpg As you can see, it works on my end.